# Не получается подключить JS файл

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте ХешКод, решил подключить библиотеку в php файлу, но он почему-то не может её подключить, вот код.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../config.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src = "../typer.js"></script>
<script src = "../engine.js"></script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "../style.css" />
<title>Кобинет модератора</title>
</head>
<body id = "container">
<style>
#back{
 background-color: gray;
 opacity: 0.4;
}

#back:hover{
 opacity: 1;
}
</style>
<center>
<div id = "back">
<input type = "submit" class = "button" value = "Список пользователей" onclick = "showAllUser()"/>
</div>
</center>
<div id = "allUser">
<b>БЛА БАЛАЩЛАЩАЬ</b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот код JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#allUser').hide(1);
});
```

Так вот если я этот JS код вставлю в сам php код между тегами <script></script> то всё работает, но когда я выношу это в отдельный файл, ничего не работает. Проверял файл в папке есть.

Comment: может с путями что то напутали? указывайте абс. путь, например - src='/assets/file.js'

Comment: Да нет вроде всё нормально, файл лежит в корне...

Comment: если в корне то ../ наверное лишнее

Comment: Да, а файл находится не в корне, он находится в папке control.

Comment: тогда /control/file.js

Answer (score 2):

Сохрани тогда файл вот так:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#allUser').hide(1);
});
</script>
```

И попробуй подключить, в php обычно когда делаешь `include`, если в файле, который мы подключаем, php код не занесён в тег `<?php ?>`, то выводится ошибка, хоть мы будем подключать его и внутри `<?php ?>`.

Comment: конечно ж нижняя часть ответа не относится к вопросу, но всё же чтобы знал )

Answer (score 1):

Всё елементарно проверяется.

В броузере жмем "просмотр страницы", как правило все броузеры подсвечивают пути. Нажимаем на линку

```
<script src = "../typer.js"></script>
```

и броузер запрашивает сам файл скрипта. и тут мы уже смотрим показывается ли js файл, если не показывается - то пишет почему не смогло показать - а если показывает - проблема не тут.

Кстати с чего вы решили что он не подключается ?